# QML.jl: No applicable_loaders found for QML

Tags: qt, user-interface, qml, julia

I am unable to use QML.jl as my code fails with the following error

```
ERROR: No applicable_loaders found for QML
Stacktrace:
 [1] error(::String) at ./error.jl:33
 [2] applicable_loaders at /home/wali/.julia/packages/FileIO/BUPwf/src/loadsave.jl:11 [inlined]
 [3] load(::String; options::Base.Iterators.Pairs{Symbol,String,Tuple{Symbol},NamedTuple{(:greeting,),Tuple{String}}}) at /home/wali/.julia/packages/FileIO/BUPwf/src/loadsave.jl:112
 [4] #3 at ./REPL[18]:17 [inlined]
 [5] mktempdir(::var"#3#4", ::String; prefix::String) at ./file.jl:709
 [6] mktempdir(::Function, ::String) at ./file.jl:707 (repeats 2 times)
 [7] top-level scope at REPL[18]:1
```

The tests for the package also fail with the same error.

Here is the code I am trying to run if that helps

```
        mktempdir() do folder
          path = joinpath(folder, "main.qml")
          write(path, """
          import QtQuick 2.0
          import QtQuick.Controls 1.0
          ApplicationWindow {
            visible: true
            Text {
              text: greeting
            }
            Timer {
              running: true
              onTriggered: Qt.quit()
            }
          }
          """)
          load(path; greeting = "Hello, World!")
          exec()
        end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem. If you use the following code snippets and especially use `loadqml()` instead of `load()`

The folder structure looks like this:

- src/

  - hello.jl
  - qml/

    - hello.qml

So I created a separated `hello.qml` file like this in a **qml** subfolder:

```
import QtQuick 2.6
import QtQuick.Controls 2.3

ApplicationWindow {
visible: true
    Text {
        text: greeting
    }
    Timer {
        running: true
        onTriggered: Qt.quit()
    }
}
```

The Julia code looks like this in hello.jl:

```
using QML
using Qt5QuickControls2_jll

qml_file = joinpath(dirname(@__FILE__), "qml", "hello.qml")

loadqml(
    qml_file,
    greeting = "Hello, World!"
)

# Start the GUI
exec()
```

If you run from `src` folder `julia hello.jl` this should return

[image]

I used Julia version **Version 1.6.3** and installed the following packages:

- Pkg.add("IJulia")
- Pkg.add("QML")
- Pkg.add("Observables")
- Pkg.add("Qt5QuickControls2_jll")
- Pkg.add("Qt5QuickControls_jll")